# Scala: map(f) and map(_.f)

Tags: scala

I thought in scala `map(f)` is the same as `map(_.f)` as `map(x => x.f)`, but turns out it is not

```
scala> val a = List(1,2,3)
val a: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3)

scala> a.map(toString)
val res7: List[Char] = List(l, i, n)

scala> a.map(_.toString)
val res8: List[String] = List(1, 2, 3)
```

What happenes when `a.map(toString)` is called? Where did the three charaacters `l`, `i`, and `n` come from?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`map(f)` is not the same as `map(_.f())`. It's the same as `map(f(_))`. That is, it's going to call `f(x)`, not `x.f()`, for each `x` in the list.

So `a.map(toString)` should be an error because the normal `toString` method does not take any arguments. My guess is that in your REPL session you've defined your own `toString` method that takes an argument and that's the one that's being called.

Comment: Actually, a stand-alone `toString` **does** exist and can be indexed via `toString.apply(x)`, which is what is happening here. Try `println(toString)` and see what you get.

Comment: @jwvh Maybe this differs between Scala versions, but for me (using Scala 2) `a.map(toString)` causes a type error because it tries to call `toString(x)`, not `toString()(x)`, and only `a.map(toString())` will end up indexing the  string returned by the REPL's `toString()`.